# Create a select LINQ query that orders by primary key without specifying the model type

Tags: c#, linq, .net-core, entity-framework-core, expression-trees

I have a process that basically moves data from one database to another and to do so there are a range of message handlers.  To allow my data move process to be dynamic I wanted to develop a generic process by using a custom attribute on my message handlers thus allowing me to drive the data migration automatically.

Each message handler has a custom attribute e.g.

`[BulkImport(EntityModelType = typeof(TblProxyCompany))]`

The implementation of the attribute is as follows: -

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class, AllowMultiple = false)]
public class BulkImportAttribute : Attribute
{
    public Type EntityModelType { get; set; }
    public Type[] DependentEntityModelTypes { get; set; }
}
```

My data migration process reads in all message handlers with this attribute which creates my task list. Within my code I loop through each task and submit a message to a local storage queue and this is where my problems started.

I need to read in a batch of rows from the table defined in my attribute via the model type i.e. `TblProxyCompany` and the linq query below does this: -

```
var query = _oltpContext.Query(importItem.EntityModelType)
  .Cast<IBulkImport>()
  .Skip(skip)
  .Take(BATCH_SIZE);
```

The first problem I encountered was that my `Query` extension method returns an IQueryable without a model type and because of this I couldn't use Skip and Take hence casting to an `IBulkImport` interface.

So I created an interface `IBulkImport` and added this to each of my model types and simply casted the `IQueryable` to `IQueryable<IBulkImport>` and now I can use Skip and Take.

I then discovered that SQL was returning my data in a consistent order and thus my batches were not correct so I now need to order the query by the primary key of the model type.  Unfortunately, although 99% of my tables do have a primary key of `Id` not all of them do so I couldn't simply add an `Id` column onto the `IBulkImport` interface :/

I can get my primary key easy enough: -

```
public virtual string GetPrimaryKey(Type entityModelType)
{
    return _oltpContext.Model
        .FindEntityType(entityModelType)
        .FindPrimaryKey().Properties
        .Select(x => x.Name).Single();
}
```

I've found loads of examples with regards creating extension methods to allow the order by column to be passed as a string but they all rely at some point on a  generic type being passed specifying the type.

I found the example below: -

```
public static IQueryable<TEntity> OrderBy<TEntity>(this IQueryable<TEntity> source, string orderByProperty,
                          bool desc) 
{
     string command = desc ? "OrderByDescending" : "OrderBy";
     var type = typeof(TEntity);
     var property = type.GetProperty(orderByProperty);
     var parameter = Expression.Parameter(type, "p");
     var propertyAccess = Expression.MakeMemberAccess(parameter, property);
     var orderByExpression = Expression.Lambda(propertyAccess, parameter);
     var resultExpression = Expression.Call(typeof(Queryable), command, new Type[] { type, property.PropertyType },
                                   source.Expression, Expression.Quote(orderByExpression));
     return source.Provider.CreateQuery<TEntity>(resultExpression);
}
```

but as you can see I need to pass the TEntity type again.  I think the casting to `IBulkImport` is where my problems start but I can't understand how to construct a LINQ statement that SELECTS, ORDERS, TAKES and PICKS when all I have to begin with is the model type i.e. TblProxyCompany as a parameter against the `BulkImport` custom attribute.

Comment: Why don't you add the `Type entityModelType` as an extra parameter and ditch `var type = typeof(TEntity);`?

Comment: I get the following error: System.InvalidOperationException: 'No generic method 'OrderBy' on type 'System.Linq.Queryable' is compatible with the supplied type arguments and arguments. No type arguments should be provided if the method is non-generic. '

Comment: Actually I think it's working, I removed the typed references and moved the order by before my cast and I think it's working!!!